# date comparison (compare a date of event with a current date)

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have a list of events and I would like to automatically hide the events which are no longer up to date. It means that I have to compare the date of every single event with a current date. So if today is 23.02.2018, the event with the date 06.01.2018 should be hidden but the event with the date 08.03.2018 should be visible. Can somebody help me, please? I am lost...

```js
var today = new Date();
var date1 = today.getFullYear() + "/" + today.getMonth() + "/" + today.getDate();
var date2 = $(".event").data("date");

date3 = new Date(date1);
date4 = new Date(date2);


  if (date3.getTime() > date4.getTime()); { 
    $(".event").hide();
    $(".event").attr("value", "");
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p><strong>EXAPLE</strong></p>
<p>Today is 23.02.2018</p>
  <div id="event-list">
  <div class="event" data-date="2018/01/06" value="search">06.01.2018 - should be hidden</div>
  <div class="event" data-date="2018/02/07" value="search">07.02.2018 - should be hidden</div>
  <div class="event" data-date="2018/03/08" value="search">08.03.2018 - should be visible</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your date1 return 23/1/2018.. cause getMonth() start at 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the `data-date` attribute to form a valid date and then compare it with today. If it is less than hide the corresponding element.

Use `jQuery.each()` to iterate all the elements matching selector. Read more about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).

```js
var today = new Date().getTime();

$("#event-list .event").each(function(){
  var eventDate = $(this).attr("data-date");
  eventDate = new Date(eventDate).getTime();
  
  if(eventDate < today)
    $(this).hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p><strong>EXAPLE</strong></p>
<p>Today is 23.02.2018</p>
  <div id="event-list">
  <div class="event" data-date="2018/01/06" value="search">06.01.2018 - should be hidden</div>
  <div class="event" data-date="2018/02/07" value="search">07.02.2018 - should be hidden</div>
  <div class="event" data-date="2018/03/08" value="search">08.03.2018 - should be visible</div>
</div>
```